# How to stop access to text files?

Tags: .htaccess, yii

In my `yii` project i have `Changelog` and `Licence` text files. I know about `RBAC` and applied it on every `Controller` but how can i prevent any guest user to view these text files. As till now anyone can view this.

I have used this in my `htaccess` file

```
<Files ~ "(.txt)">
Order allow, deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

But this is worked for `txt file` and these files have no `extension`

Comment: How many files are there **in approx.** on which you want to deny access and also the files have similar names or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can block access to all the files without extension using this rule in your site root .htaccess or Apache config/vhost file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
# if there is no extension then block
RewriteRule ^[^.]+$ - [F]
```

Answer (score 0):

You question is a little board, and so the answer is a little general. but there are a couple approaches;

**option 1.** remove the Changelog and Licence files? if these are yii install changelog and licence then they dont need to be left on the server. just ensure you complying with the licence requirements.

**option 2.** 
you mentioned "guest user" which htaccess is not going to integrate well with yii for authorized users. you could move the files into a folder with a .htaccess containing a single line `Deny from all`. this blocks everyone except the PHP executed on your server.

you can now create a method/action in a controller which just echos the file contents. [file-get-contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php). wrap this your authentication so only non-guest users are able to use the method.

if there are only two static files, then maybe just an 'action' for each. if its many files that are changing names etc, then you accept an id to the controller pass to a model that uses [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) and checks the [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) really [exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) and spits out your output to view.

**option 2.1** 
instead of folder with a .htaccess you could also move the files to the parent of the webhost base dir if you have this access. this means that your webserver can not serve the file, but the php can still reach it with local paths.

**option 3**
in .htaccess you can use AuthType [basic](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PasswordBasicAuth) and will invoke your webserver to prompt the user for username and password as configured in the .htaccess. this is problematic as the interface is not user friendly and is very difficult to integrate with your webapps user db.

**option 4**
.htaccess can support other [AuthType](http://www.widexl.com/tutorials/htaccess.html)s but option 2 becomes much easier at this point.